# Trying to detect a verification code in Xcode on x86_64

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, text, textfield

I'm trying to detect when a verification code is entered into a text field, so like if I wanted someone to type in "this is a test.", it would then run the following code:

```
system("say this is a test");
```

But I keep getting the error "void value not ignored as it ought to be". I have no idea what this means. This is what I have so far, but I think I need some other help in which I'll explain below the code.

```
if ([SpecialCodeTextField setStringValue:[@"this is a test." stringValue]])
{
    system("say this is a test");
}
```

But if I did something on the iPhone SDK, I could do something like:

```
if (MyTextField.text = @"this is a test")
{
    [firstView setHidden:YES];
    [secondView setHidden:NO];
}
```

Or something like that. So what is *** MyTextField.text = @"this is a test" *** on the x86_64 architecture, or when programming for Mac? I'll do a little school equation for you here:

`MyTextField.text = @"this is a test";` is to *Changing textfield text on an iPhone*

as

???????????????????????????? is to *Changing textfield text on a Mac*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all take a look into the documentation of `NSControl`.
In your first example you are messaging a `NSControl` to set a string value.
(BTW. when you use the `@"Whatever String"` notation you implicitly create a static `NSString` object, so there is no need to call `stringValue`).

However, the documentation for `-setStringValue:` says that the message returns `void`,
but your `if` structure expects any value to check.

In your second example, your code does two things.
1.) It assigns the text member of MyTextField @"this is a test".
2.) The if structure tests the text for nil.

What exactly do you want? If you want to check the `NSTextField` if its not `nil`, you would do something like this

```
if([specialCodeTextField stringValue]){
  ...
}
```

If you want to check if the `textValue` in your `NSTextField` contains "this is a test" you would do something like this:

```
if([[specialCodeTextField stringValue] isEqualToString:@"this is a test"]) {
  ...
}
```